# An error occurred: Exception setting "X": "The property 'X' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set."

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV file that I am importing using Powershell, and the file is being imported correctly because I can check its structure using following commands:

```
$P = Import-Csv -Path $env:temp\test.csv -Delimiter "," 
$P[0].PSObject.Properties.Name
$P | Get-Member -MemberType Properties | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

But unfortunately when I am trying to modify any of the columns:

```
foreach ($row in $P) {
    $row.'X' = $row.'X' -replace ',', ' '
}
```

I am getting the following error:
**An error occurred: Exception setting "X": "The property 'X' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set."**

I can't even check the type of any of the columns, because this command also returns the exact same error:

```
 $data[0].X.GetType()
```

No matter which column I choose, it always gives me the same error, even though when I display the Headers, the column is there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This look fine... Please include a code block representing a trimmed down csv with a couple of records so we can try with a csv similar to yours. Your Foreach is fine. Did you check the value of $p to see what it contained ? If you replace your $row.x line by `Write-Host $row`, you should see a pscustomObject being printed along with the properties / values. (eg: `@{x=3; y=4; z=5}`).

Comment: What is the output when you enumerate the property names? Does `X` appear? Can you show us the first few lines from the CSV you're testing with?

Comment: Check the headers in the file and make sure there’s no leading / trailing *quoted* spaces around the ```X``` column header - the property *could* be called something like ```X ``` - [x space] - rather than just ```X``` which might not be obvious from ```$P[0].PSObject.Properties.Name```. You could also try ```$P[0].PSObject.Properties.Name | foreach-object { “‘$_’ ($($_.Length))” }``` instead to show if there are any “hidden” characters in the property names. Adding the first couple of  lines of your csv to your question would help per @MathiasR.Jessen’s comment…